# php выводить определенное значения в многомерном массиве всегда первым

Tags: php

Может есть решения по адекватней чтоль ?

```
$result = [['aaa','aaaa','aaa'],['1111','1111','1111'],['bbb','bb','bbb'],['ссс','сс','ссс']];

  foreach ($result as $key=>$value){
        if ($value[1] == 'bb'){
            $a = $result[$key];
            unset($result[$key]);
            array_unshift($result,$a);
            break;
        }
    }

    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: нет, и так норм. если массив из базы, то можно прямо в запросе сортирнуть

Comment: Можно. Отсортируйте массив, используя функцию сортировки https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php

Comment: usort не особо подходит для этой задачи

Comment: можете обойтись без `$a` уменьшив код на строчку